# Parsing json with broken remote API

Tags: java, json, kotlin, moshi, jsonparser

Here is my model class

`data class Article(
        val id: Int? = 0,
        val is_local: Boolean? = false,
        val comments: List<Comment?>? = listOf())`

and here is json

```
  {
    "id": 33,
    "is_local": "true",
    "comments":
         [
          { "url": "aaa" },

          { "url": "bbb" },

          { "url": "ccc" )

     ]

}
```

i am using this custom Adapter to return default value in case of parsing error like in my case is **is_local** field

```
class DefaultOnDataMismatchAdapter<T> private constructor(private val delegate: 
   JsonAdapter<T>, private val defaultValue: T?) : JsonAdapter<T>() {

 @Throws(IOException::class)
  override fun fromJson(reader: JsonReader): T? =
        try {
            delegate.fromJsonValue(reader.readJsonValue())
        } catch (e: Exception) {
            println("Wrongful content - could not parse delegate " + 
delegate.toString())
            defaultValue
        }

@Throws(IOException::class)
override fun toJson(writer: JsonWriter, value: T?) {
    delegate.toJson(writer, value)
}

  companion object {
    @JvmStatic
    fun <T> newFactory(type: Class<T>, defaultValue: T?): 
    JsonAdapter.Factory {
        return object : JsonAdapter.Factory {
            override fun create(requestedType: Type, annotations: 
      Set<Annotation>, moshi: Moshi): JsonAdapter<*>? {
                if (type != requestedType) {
                    return null
                }
                val delegate = moshi.nextAdapter<T>(this, type, 
          annotations)
                return DefaultOnDataMismatchAdapter(delegate, 
     defaultValue)
             }

         }
      }
   }

}
```

and my test fail and boolean value is not false i have added the above adapter to moshi

```
@Before
fun createService() {

    val moshi = Moshi.Builder()


    .add(DefaultOnDataMismatchAdapter
                           .newFactory(Boolean::class.java,false))
            .add(KotlinJsonAdapterFactory())
            .build()

    val retrofit = Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl(mockWebServer.url("/"))
            .addConverterFactory(MoshiConverterFactory.create(moshi))
            .build()

    service =  retrofit.create(ApiStores::class.java)



}




@Test
fun getBooleanParsingError() {

    enqueueResponse(case1)

    val article = service.getArticle().execute()

    assert(article.body()!!).isNotNull()
    assert(article.body()!!.is_local).isEqualTo(false)  // test fail here 

}
```

but when i change the datatype of is_local field in the model class to not nullable it works

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that types `kotlin.Boolean` and `kotlin.Boolean?` correspond to 2 different Java types:

- `kotlin.Boolean` is `boolean` Java primitive type
- `kotlin.Boolean?` is `java.lang.Boolean` Java type

In your test you created an adapter for a `kotlin.Boolean` (i.e., Java `boolean` type), while in your data model you have a `kotlin.Boolean?` (i.e., a `java.lang.Boolean` type).
For this reason, when method `create(...)` of the `Factory` gets called, you are in a situation where `type != requestedType`, so your adapter is not created and the `KotlinJsonAdapter` is used instead.
At this point, since the `is_local` field of the Json is **not** a boolean (but a string), Moshi should raise an Exception.

If you change your data model or your adapter to use the same type, you are in a situation where `type == requestedType`, so your adapter gets created, the exception is thrown as before, but you added a `catch` block that returns the default value.

Comment: i am using Boolean::class.java  how can i use kotlin.Boolean?  type ? in order to compare type == requestedType

Comment: you can use `Boolean::class.javaObjectType` to get an instance of the Java Class for `java.lang.Boolean`